# How can i check similar entries in an array and according to similar entries merge the values using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data like

```
[
  { "day": "Mon", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Tue", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Wed", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Thu", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Fri", "time": "11:00AM – 11:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Sat", "time": "11:00AM – 11:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Sun", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" }
]
```

What i want to is like if the time is same for **Sun** to **Thu** it will become

```
[
  {"day":"Sun-Thu", "time":"11:00AM – 10:00PM"},
  {"day":"Fri-Sat","time":"11:00AM – 11:00PM"}
]
```

I have tried

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < jsonData.length;) {
    if (jsonData[i].time == jsonData[j].time) {

      var hour = {
        day: jsonData[i].day + "-" + jsonData[j].day,
        time: jsonData[i].time
      }
      arr.push(hour);
      jsonData.splice(i, 1);
      jsonData.splice(j - 1, 1);
    } else {
      j++;
    }
  }
}
```

but it is producing

```
[
  {"day":"Sun","time":"11:00AM – 10:00PM"},
  {"day":"Mon-Tue","time":"11:00AM – 10:00PM"},
  {"day":"Wed-Thu","time":"11:00AM – 10:00PM"},
  {"day":"Fri-Sat","time":"11:00AM – 11:00PM"}
]
```

Please help me how can i get expected data.

thanks..!

Comment: you want to group by time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var arr = [{ "day": "Mon", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" },{ "day": "Tue", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" },{ "day": "Wed", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" },{ "day": "Thu", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" },{ "day": "Fri", "time": "11:00AM – 11:00PM" },{ "day": "Sat", "time": "11:00AM – 11:00PM" },{ "day": "Sun", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" }];

// Set "Sun" as first day of the week
arr.unshift(arr.pop());

var result = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  // check if the time of the last range is the same as the time of the current element.
  let same = a.length && a[a.length - 1].time === c.time && a[a.length - 1];
  if(same){
     // replace the last day of the range (if any) with the day of the current element
     same.day = same.day.replace(/\-.*$/, "") + "-" + c.day;
  }else{
    // add the current element to the result array because its time is not the same as the time of the last element.
    a.push(c)
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Answers on SO shouldn't be "try this". They should explain the problem and the solution. Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tho I upvoted your solution as it is pretty elegant, you should do better with the "pop Sunday on the top of the list" part. It could be Saturday-Thursday on the next array, Friday-Monday on the one after, etc.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've added some comments to try to explain what the code does.

Comment: That's just a little better, but I doubt someone with limited experience will have a clue as to what the code means. Your comments say what the code does, but no explanations of regular expression syntax, arrow function syntax, the `.reduce()` method, etc. not even any links to resources where someone could learn more about those things.

Comment: There's a bug in this code if there's a gap in the days – example `[ {day: 'Mon', ...}, {day: 'Wed', ...}, ...]`

Comment: @naomik Yes, there are definitely a lot of bugs because I made some assumption about the input. I'm assuming the input will always have 7 elements starting with "Mon" and the output is supposed to consider the week as starting from "Sun".

Answer (score -2):

**try this hint**

```
var a = [
  { "day": "Mon", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Tue", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Wed", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Thu", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Fri", "time": "11:00AM – 11:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Sat", "time": "11:00AM – 11:00PM" }, 
  { "day": "Sun", "time": "11:00AM – 10:00PM" }
]

var b = a.filter(function(rm){return rm.time == "11:00AM – 11:00PM"})

var t = {}

for(var i =0;i<b.length;i++){
if(t[b[i].time]){
t[b[i].time] = t[b[i].time]+"-"+ b[i].day
}else{
t[b[i].time] = b[i].day
}
}
```

Comment: Answers on SO shouldn't be hints. They should explain the problem and the solution. Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).